# I need a virus scanner to scan files for windows that i am going to send/receive from other users who will also be using windows as their os

Tags: scanner

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on My system and i want to scan the files on my external storage devices before passing them to others. I read the page at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Antivirus and tried

1. Bitdefender Antivirus Scanner for Unices which gave me an error during automatic updating which an error code, so i tied to manually update Bitdefender Scanner for Unices by downloading the cumulative zip archive from there site but that failed too.So i gave up on it.
2. Avast was the brand i trust the most, But it looks like Avast! Linux Home Edition appears to be old and no longer maintained,more like dropped by the dev team.
3. Comodo Anti-Virus for Linux - I have had a really bad experience with Comodo Anti-Virus for Windows a few years ago So I prefer not to use this now,I maybe wrong now because i dont know how its now like.So correct me if i am wrong.
4. AVG Antivirus- similar story as Comodo Anti-Virus.
5. Avira Antivirus and Panda Antivirus - no longer maintained/terminated
6. F-PROT Antivirus for Workstations (home users) - Looks outdated too,Correct me if i am wrong.
   and Finally the **Open Source Antivirus**
7. ClamAV Antivirus- First i installed ClamAV( from terminal because i could not find it on the ubuntu software center(Why?) then ClamTK from the ubuntu software center But ClamTK was freezing/Failing while it was running.

So I am asking the community here for an appropriate solution for this issue of mine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's a downside when you permanently install Antivirus on Linux - it installs antivirus live-scan daemon (service), that eats your computer resources, while obviously you don't need it on Linux, you only need to have an anti-virus scanner.

I used ClamAV on my ubuntu server to find malicious scripts on my websites.

But here I want to recommend you to try free Dr.Web CureIt Live-USB scanner. You can't install it into your Ubuntu, there are only live CD and USB options. Its Live USB is based on Linux. But it works great and they update it everyday. They also have free scanner for Windows, you could try to open it in ubuntu with Wine.

http://www.freedrweb.com/livedisk/ - Live CD/USB
https://www.freedrweb.com/download+cureit+free/?lng=en - Windows scanner

Answer (score 0):

I've tested ESET Nod32 for Linux and it's very good if you want a desktop solution. It's not free though. If you're going to try it, don't install libc6-i386 as prompted, install libc6:i386 instead or you're going to experience freezing problems.
At the end I've settled on Sophos (being it free). It's command line driven, very light on resources and unintrusive.
They have both performed very well in indipendent anti-virus tests.